# Gyroscope not working for some games on Samsung Galaxy SII ICS and JB

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gyroscope

The gyroscope works fine for most apps, and for all uses within the OS. But for some game apps, both temple runs and 100 Doors for example, it will not work at all. It's remained a problem after I've upgraded from Ice Cream Sandwich to Jelly Bean. Seems really strange, but perhaps someone knows what's going on and better yet how to fix it? Thanks.